# extract values from xml tags with identical names in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a C# .NET app that contains a dynamically generated xml document. It tracks order info, such as name, date the order was placed, all that sort of stuff. I have no issue extracting the information contained in these tags using innerText.

However, when the order is 'built' by our customer, they are allowed to attach files....

Each file is saved in the xml doc under the tag

So I end up with something (simplified) like this:

```
<order>
   <Number>1</Number>
   <Email>example@stack.com</Email>
   <Date>2012-08-13</Date>
   <File>File1.txt</File>
   <File>File2.txt</File>
</order>
```

As I said, I extract the other info using

```
   foreach (XmlElement element in file.SelectNodes("/order"))
   {
       String strNumber = element.SelectSingleNode("Number").InnerText,
               strEmail = element.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText,
                strDate = element.SelectSingleNode("Date").InnerText;
   }
```

However when I do this with name, I get an error honking about not being set to an instance... Which I totally understand.

My question is, how can I get this info? There can be any number of Files attached, from zero to however many the user wants.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are already doing it with "order". You need to do the same `foreach` loop inside the "order" `foreach` loop!

Comment: Oh God... Massive brain let down on that one. How embarrassing. Thank you. I feel like such a boob....

Comment: @banging - I would love to mark up your answer.. Throw it up there so I can give you cred. Turns out (it's been a bit since I've worked with XML) that I wasn't pathing out the node fully... Forgot my XPATH essentials.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code example.

Order represent xml order

```
[TestFixture]
public class ForTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var root = XElement.Load("order.xml");
        var order = CreateOrder(root);
    }

    private Order CreateOrder(XElement element)
    {
        var result = new Order
        {
            Number = int.Parse(element.Element("Number").Value),
             Date = DateTime.Parse(element.Element("Date").Value),
            Email = element.Element("Email").Value,
            Files = element.Descendants("File").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
        };
        return result;
    }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<string> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using serialization if you know the properties

```
[XmlRoot("order")]
public class order
{
[XmlElement("Number")]
public string  Number{get;set;}
[XmlElement("Email")]
public string  Email{get;set;}
[XmlElement("Date")]
public string  Date{get;set;}
[XmlElement("File")]
public string[] File{get;set;}
}
```

The below code is to deserialize

```
    public static T DeSerializeXMLString<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xmlString));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
```

Comment: What about *using* near stream/writer

Comment: @GSerjo could you please explain your comment in detail. I couldn't understand.

Comment: using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xmlString))){...}

Comment: Got it :) Does it matter here. Its just a quick code to show how to handle the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ based solution:

```
XDocument XMLDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile.xml");
var LoadInfo =  from Node in XMLDoc.Descendants("order")                       
                select new
                  {
                    Number = Node.Element("Number").Value,
                    Email = Node.Element("Email").Value,
                    Date = Node.Element("Date").Value,
                    File = Node.Element("File").Value,
                  };
```

Usage:

```
    foreach(var Info in LoadInfo)
    {
      //Do something with the info.
      //Console.WriteLine(Info.Email);
    }
```